# NameError: name 'gensim' is not defined

Tags: python, gensim, lda, mallet

I've imported all the packages I need

```
from gensim import corpora
from gensim import models
from gensim.models import LdaModel
from gensim.models import TfidfModel
from gensim.models import CoherenceModel
```

and then I need to run the LdaMallet model so I import them like this

```
from gensim.models.wrappers import LdaMallet
```

when run the code below, I've got some `Namerror`:

```
mallet_path = 'mallet-2.0.8/bin/mallet' # update this path

ldamallet = gensim.models.wrappers.LdaMallet(mallet_path,corpus=corpus, num_topics=20, id2word=dictionary)
```

Error occurred:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-1c656d4f8c21> in <module>()
      1 mallet_path = 'mallet-2.0.8/bin/mallet' # update this path
      2 
----> 3 ldamallet = gensim.models.wrappers.LdaMallet(mallet_path,corpus=corpus, num_topics=20, id2word=dictionary)

NameError: name 'gensim' is not defined
```

I thought I've imported all the things that I need, and the lda model ran well before I tried to use mallet. So what's the problem?

Comment: I'm not a Python expert, but I'm pretty sure that doing `from gensim import models` means you need to refer to `models.wrappers`, etc., not `gensim.models.wrappers`. Please let me know if that's helpful, and I can add it as an answer.

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gensim.wrappers'

Comment: now I have a new problem,I just import gensim and run it again,a new error occorred'CalledProcessError: Command 'mallet-2.0.8/bin/mallet import-file --preserve-case --keep-sequence --remove-stopwords --token-regex "\S+" --input /var/folders/br/txtq3sps39sgn70v4tlm17q40000gn/T/2ab601_corpus.txt --output /var/folders/br/txtq3sps39sgn70v4tlm17q40000gn/T/2ab601_corpus.mallet' returned non-zero exit status 1.'

Comment: it seems that I need to install the JDK to use java command  line,but how can I install it?I've tried in various ways before but failed

Answer (score 2):

Because you have this `import`:

```
from gensim import models
```

you would need to refer to `wrappers` in your code as `models.wrappers`, etc., not `gensim.models.wrappers`.

But you're also doing this:

```
from gensim.models.wrappers import LdaMallet
```

so you can just refer to LdaMallet directly, as in:

```
ldamallet = LdaMallet(mallet_path,corpus=corpus, num_topics=20, id2word=dictionary)
```

Note that I left out the `gensim.models.wrappers.` here; you don't need it.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `LdaMallet(mallet_path,corpus=corpus, num_topics=20, id2word=dictionary)` straightaway because you already have imported the required method from `gensim.models.wrappers`